# Bootstrap 3 Carousel is not sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

So i've got a problem with the sliding. 
It just won't slide! 
The pictures are more like hovering each other or fading, but there won't be any sliding movement.

Does anyone got an idea how this comes and what i did wrong? 
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>and</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/Slider/Earth_slider.png" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>First Slider</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/Slider/Rosetta_slider.png" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Second Slider</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/Slider/Showreel_slider.png" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Second Slider</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>



<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 1000
    })​;
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Only that carousel is not a function. It means the one i've written in the script at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the basic `Bootstrap.js` without the `Carousel` component.

Install `Bootstrap.js` with `Carousel.js/.css` otherwise, you need to add `Carousel.js` to your page separately.

You can choose the desired bundle here:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: How do i get this file alone? the carousel.js?

Comment: See the link in my answer.

Comment: I downloaded but it's still not sliding. i included the bootstrap.min.js

Comment: You need the .css file too.

Comment: One quick question. I had a lot of styling done with less before it, now i changed the bootstrap css. can i get the other less dates into this one again? I compiled the bootstrap.less but it's not working.

Comment: The .less should have had everything bundled in to. See about getting the bundle in .less format, not sure this will work with 2 different files now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to init jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 1000
      })​;
    }
</script>
```

Or try with markdown into your div

```
data-ride="carousel"
```

Comment: I did this at the end just after including the js scripts and before the /body /html tags

Comment: You do not have to init it this way, you can init it through data attributes.

Comment: Still it's not sliding :/

Comment: @ZeeTee I have those data attributes form bootstrap in it but it doesn't do anything

Comment: change the script declaration order. First jquery and then bootstrap js files ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need `carousel.js` called in your script. Also you need to define your Javascript like

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
  });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/moyeen52/erf70gdw/) is the fiddle you can try.